# Calculating Area using Sigma Notation

Tags: calculus, summation, riemann-sum

This is my second time posting.  Thanks again for answering my first question.
This is my question:

Find the area above y = 0, from x = -1 to x = 1 of y = 2^x.  Use subintervals of equal length.  I started with this summation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2}{n}\left(2^{2i/n}\right)$$

I am not sure where to go next. I was trying to factor using exponents laws to get the sum into a form so that a summation formula could be applied to get the sum into closed form.  I do have the solution, but I don't understand how they got to the step right after this:

Here is the solution:

[image]

If anyone could help me, that would be fantastic.
Thank you guys for your time.

Comment: In the given solution, do you have trouble with the first line? Or going from the first line to the second? Or in going from the second to the third?

Answer (score 1):

You've made an error in representing a Riemann sum for $2^x$. The $2^{2i/n}$ in your summands should be $2^{-1 + 2i/n}$. Remember, you're partitioning the interval $[-1,1]$, not $[0,2]$. So your sum should be $$\sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{2}{n}\cdot2^{-1+2j/n}$$ which is the same as  $$\frac{2}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^n 2^{-1}(2^{2/n})^j = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^n (2^{2/n})^j$$ The last sum can be written $$\frac{2^{2/n}}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^n (2^{2/n})^{j-1}$$ which, by the way, is the same as $$\frac{2^{2/n}}{n}[1 + 2^{2/n} + (2^{2/n})^2 + \cdots + (2^{2/n})^{n-1}]$$ as expressed in the solution.

Comment: After that, the sum is rearranged in such a way as to use the geometric series; then computing the limit of this geometric series divided by $n$ requires a L'Hopital's rule problem. (It might be good to include this in the answer.)